# How to find [ul] and replace with [list] in db colum

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i've just migrated Forum system and it seems that they don't use the same BBcode terminology for a List. In my old version the BBcode was [ul][li] but in my new one list is simply [list]

I've tried to write a script that slects the posts where in the colum Content '[ul]

```
"SELECT at6ln_discuss_posts.id FROM at6ln_discuss_posts WHERE at6ln_discuss_posts.content = 'ul'";
```

but for some reason i can't Select it let alone start replacing. any ideas what i may be doing wrong?

best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I export the sql with phpmyadmin and then use a text editor like sublime text to do replacements like this. It's less hassle than to do it in SQL, but it's maybe not a good idea if the site is online and constantly active. You should make sure that no content has changed when you re-import the updated sql.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Like` instead of `=`

```
"SELECT at6ln_discuss_posts.id FROM at6ln_discuss_posts WHERE at6ln_discuss_posts.content LIKE '%ul%'";
```